# Can you make a locked coin fountain?

Tags: xlm

I've got a kinda weird idea about how business and cryptocurrencies could work together. The idea requires a DEX (like Stellar has), the ability for people to make their own tokens (like Stellar has) and the ability to make a locked coin fountain (does Stellar have this?).

Essentially, is it possible to do the following with the current API?

Create a new token.
Setup something that sends 1 token/time period (such as a second) to a specified wallet.
Lock the token such that there is no other way to generate more of the token (thereby creating a single, known rate way of new coins being created).
Is that something you can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not natively with Stellar only no.

However this would be a great use case for the Turrets l2 smart contracting protocol being developed. https://tss.stellar.org/

If decentralization is important TSS is probably the way to go atm, otherwise you could do this on your own server. The cron nature wouldn’t be something TSS would handle but you could build it such that anyone could hit the Turret txFunction endpoint and if it’s time the fountain would spit out a coin. Similar to how Stellar inflation worked back in the day.

You should post a link to this question in the TSS Discord server in the use case ideas channel. https://discord.gg/TpRmYXQQzP